# Anchor doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm a beginner with Javascript and I've some issues with my website...
I'm using fullPage.js script and another script for a vertical menu with hidden submenu.
My script for nav menu is not working with fullPage.js. Looks great but my anchors don't work anymore.

I'm probably doing a mistake somewhere but I can't find where.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.fullpage({
        verticalCentered: false,
        resize: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 750,
        easing: 'easeInQuad',
        navigation: false,
        navigationPosition: 'left',
        navigationTooltips: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
        slidesNavigation: true,
        slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
        loopBottom: false,
        loopTop: true,
        loopHorizontal: false,
        autoScrolling: true,
        scrollOverflow: false,
        css3: false,
        paddingTop: '3em',
        paddingBottom: '10px',
        normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
        keyboardScrolling: true,
        touchSensitivity: 5,
        continuousVertical: false,
        animateAnchor: true,
        //events
        onLeave: function (index, direction) {},
        afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {},
        afterRender: function () {},
        afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {},
        onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {}
    });
});
```

```js
$(function () {
    var menu_ul = $('.menu > li > ul'),
        menu_a = $('.menu > li > a');
    menu_ul.hide();
    menu_a.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            menu_a.removeClass('active');
            menu_ul.filter(':visible').slideUp('slow');
            $(this).addClass('active').next().stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="section" id="section0">
    <!-- SECTION HOME PAGE -->
    <h1>earth. home. destroyed.</h1>
    <div id="content">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="item0"><a href="#section0">home page</a></li>
            <li class="item1"><a>releases</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="subitem"><a>discography</a></li>
                    <li class="subitem"><a>videos</a></li>
                    <li class="subitem"><a>remixes</a></li>
                </ul>

            <li class="item2"><a href="#section1">subscribe</a></li>
            <li class="item3"><a>follow</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="subitem"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/">facebook</a></li>
                    <li class="subitem"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/">twitter</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item4"><a href="#section2">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing `</li>` somewhere.

Comment: This is why it's important to keep code indentation clean. Compare with the original code : http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/fdf0eed2-a4d5-4b9d-abf6-e46af4e61ae4/view-source.

Comment: erf i'm sorry, i don't know what happened with the copy/paste :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using anchors in your fullpage.js plugin.
You might have deleted the line.

You will need something like:

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#myMenu'
});
```

You shouldn't be using the initialization that you posted. That's just an example showed [on the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#initialization) with all the possible options (except the `anchors` and `slidesColor` that your removed).

Use only the options you need taking into consideration the default values of each of them which are detailed [at the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options).
It doesn't make sense to have things like `paddingTop: '3em',` if you are not going to use `padding` at all.

Comment: Thank you very much !! It works perfectly now ! Thank you for your great script and I promise I'll give you credits in the website and some $$$. Thank youuu, have a great day ! 
xx

Answer (score 1):

because you are using event.preventDefault() in your anchor click event which will restrict the page from redirecting. Remove that one,

```
menu_a.click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        menu_a.removeClass('active');
        menu_ul.filter(':visible').slideUp('slow');
        $(this).addClass('active').next().stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It doesn't work for me but I probably forget something.